# Tool or script to extract a list of non-built-in modules/packages in a Python project/repo?

Tags: python

Sometimes, I like to check a Python project's *install_requires* in *setup.py* to see if there is some Python modules/packages missing.

- Given a Python project. Ex, cloned from a repo.
- Assume all *.py* files are located under a folder. Ex, *src/*.
- A smarter tool, Python package scanner (like a smarter *ack*), to scan the folder and get a list of *imported non-built-in Python modules/packages*.
- The tool just does static analysis/scanning, not a dynamic importing because some modules/packages might not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pylint for this type of static analysis.   It will highlight any broken imports(http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:f0401)